# Does tension vary across length of rod when there is no acceleration?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics

I know that Tension $T$ across elements of rod will vary in the case when the rod is moving with acceleration, and for each element tension acting will be equal to $ma$ (towards left) where $a$ is the common acceleration of rod and $m$ is the mass of the portion of rod beyond that section (towards right of that section) and therefore making the tension across elements of rod "non uniform" . As in this case
[image]

However in cases where there is no acceleration in the rod, but say the linear mass density of rod is changing from one end to the other end (and hence one can argue that the rod is not "uniform") will the tension across all the elements of the rod be uniform?
[image]

Personally I cant find any reason for it to be so. Would like to hear your opinion

Answer (score 0):

For the rod at rest, consider a segment within the rod.  The net force on this segment is the difference between the tension at each end of the segment.  Since the segment is at rest the tension at each end of the segment is the same.  Tension is force; the stress (force per unit area) can be different at each end of the segment if the cross sectional area of the rod varies.  If the cross sectional area is constant, the stress is the same but the strain at each end can be different.

Comment: I'm assuming constant area here

Comment: OK.   I edited my comment.  The strain could be different at each end of the segment in this case.

Comment: Why would the strain be different if stress is same isn't $strain = stress/K$  where $K$ = Youngs modulus?

Comment: The material could be weaker at one end if it is less dense.